# SQL Select - Distinct - Random

Tags: sql, random, distinct

these are fields of my table table1 (position, club, country, flag) and

and I need to show randomly club name without repeating the country,

a use this query

```
select top 4 position 
from table1 where flag = 0 
and exists(select distinct country from table1) order by newid()
```

but turns out to repeat the name of the country,

can you help me?

thank you,

AM

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What is the `exists(select distinct...` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to pick a random club from each country?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, and tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to select distinct country and club , use  DISTINCT key word . Else please provide what is your select clause should contain.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SQL Server, and I'm trying to pick at random from different countries 4 clubs, ...

club country                    correct option

benfica Portugal
chelsea england
inter italy
madrid spain

club    country    incorrect option

benfica Portugal
chelsea england
man utd england
madrid spain

tks,

AM